# JQuery - How to detect if a user is scrolling from the top of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a monopage website with a video in the first "slide" and I need to start the video every time the user scrolls from the top of the page.

I've tried:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() <= 1){
        $video.get(0).play();
    }
});
```

but it has unconsistent behaviors between different browser (in Firefox is ok, in Chrome the video starts when I load the page, in IE the video doesn't start at all...) and the video starts also when I scroll from the bottom to the top of the page

Comment: When the page is loaded he scroll position is top only, so eventually everyone will start from top only.

Comment: Yep, but the problem is that everytime the user returns to the top and then moves from there, I need to restart the video